# sql - delete rows which are less than a value using rank and groupby

Tags: sql, oracle12c, rank

In a table I have flows and runs

for every flow i have to keep the row with max runs delete remaining all. This has to be done of all flows.

Using single statement.

I tried to use cte, rank but getting error.

I tried to group by flows and then apply rank for the group and then delete rows which are > 1.

```
WITH cte AS 

( SELECT flow, RANK() OVER 

       (PARTITION BY flow ORDER BY runs) 

AS rank FROM TEST_RESULTS_TABLE GROUP BY flow )

DELETE FROM cte WHERE rank >1 ;


this is giving :

ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 25 Column: 153
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support updatable CTEs.  Instead, you can do:

```
delete from test_results_table trt
    where runs > (select min(trt2.runs)
                  from test_results_table trt2
                  where trt2.flow = trt.flow
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `RANK()` query (without the `GROUP BY`) and correlate it with the `DELETE` statement using the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```
DELETE FROM test_results_table
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY flow ORDER BY runs ASC ) AS rnk
    FROM   test_results_table
  )
  WHERE rnk > 1
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9f2fca85592b957bff423f6b27fa74b)*